# VBScript that exports filtered information from excel onto a webpage?

Tags: html, vba, excel, vbscript

I'm extremely new to VBScript and have been trying to figure this out for the last couple of days, searching hundreds (literally) of forums/websites and can't find a solution to meet my needs so here goes :P.

I currently have a spreadsheet that contains a large list of customer details, for example;

MPN | Manager's Name | Question?

077 | John Smith     | Yes

077 | Jane York      | No

I'm trying to extract the information to a webpage, or even possibly a new excel file but have the option of only displaying cells that have "No" to the question and filtering them so the managers are seperate

So far, I have;

```
Sub testing123()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="P:\book.xls"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$4:$K$65536").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "=Question", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Yes"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="P:\book123.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
    Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    CreateBackup:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

The code above resides in a separate excel sheet, it opens the main workbook, filters the information (question=yes) and saves it as a different name.
My aim is to be able to extract the information onto a different sheet but directly extract only the filtered information, and be sort able depending on managers name for example.

I'm so sorry if this is hard to understand, and I apologize for the lack of relevant code to display, but please if you need anymore information just let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing something like this?  I know it doesn't match what you're doing exactly, but it's an alternate approach:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim intSourceRowNum As Integer
    intSourceRowNum = 2
    Dim intDestRowNum As Integer
    intDestRowNum = 1
    Dim objSourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set objSourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim objDestSheet As Worksheet
    Set objDestSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    Do Until IsEmpty(objSourceSheet.Cells(intSourceRowNum, 1))
        If (StrComp(objSourceSheet.Cells(intSourceRowNum, 3).Value, "Yes", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
            objDestSheet.Cells(intDestRowNum, 1).Value = objSourceSheet.Cells(intSourceRowNum, 1).Value
            objDestSheet.Cells(intDestRowNum, 2).Value = objSourceSheet.Cells(intSourceRowNum, 2).Value
            objDestSheet.Cells(intDestRowNum, 3).Value = objSourceSheet.Cells(intSourceRowNum, 3).Value
            intDestRowNum = intDestRowNum + 1
        End If

        intSourceRowNum = intSourceRowNum + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Basically, it loops through all rows with data in the source sheet and only writes the values from each source row to the destination sheet if the source row matches your criteria.

Comment: That sounds awesome im going to try it when i get back home! Thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: It actually doesn't do anything :(

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you elaborate?  I tested the code as I built it, and it worked.

Comment: Well i added it as a module and assigned the macro to a button, pressed ot and nothing happened. Really sorry im extremely new to this

Comment: I tested the sub by putting the cursor right inside the body of the sub and then clicking the "execute" button.  You could try setting a break point just inside the subroutine and see if your macro button is at least getting inside the method body, then go from there.